# Can't figure out what i've done wrong

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to programming and I'm currently trying to do a simple game in Unity.

The code makes some things dissapear when they touch the ground and it works well but the "Evaporated" variable does not update in the Unity Inspector. When something touch the ground, evaporated should be incremented, but it stays at 0.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;

public class EnemyEvaporate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Enemy;
    public int Evaporated;
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision CollisionInfo)
        { 
             if (CollisionInfo.gameObject.name == "Map" || CollisionInfo.gameObject.name == "Player")
                 {
                     Thread.Sleep(15);
                     gameObject.SetActive(false);
                     Evaporated++;
                 }
        }  
}
```

Comment: Hi, is evaporated initialized before being incremented ? Is the code path executed ? ("is one of the if's before true") Do you get any exceptions ?

Comment: Note that question titles are expected to be descriptive of the problem you're experiencing. "Can't figure out what I've done wrong" gives no indication to what this question is about.

Comment: It's initialized with 0 and he code executed without any problems.

Comment: John,thanks for advice,it's my first post on this site.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code aside from maybe it not running. If you add Debug.Log("Code is running fine!"); line inside your if statement does it show up were you expect?

Comment: Yes it does,it even makes the object dissapear.But i want to add a score system that increses everytime a thing dissapear(so the score will be equal to the evaporated variable,but the variable stays at 0)

Comment: are you sure the things its colliding with are Map or name? and dear lord please remove the thread.sleep from there

Comment: Why do i have to remove the Thread.Sleep?without it the collision happends instantly and i think it looks weird

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what's the behavior you're trying to get in this script. If Evaporated is some kind of 'Global counter' for score, it need to be written different and not store inside script for this gameObject.
It might be related to your gameObject.SetActive(false) which will deactivate your object, so in fact it will disables also the scripts connected with it (and especially this one. [SetActive documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html)) and removes them from Update() for a given gameObject (so given enemy. If you have 4 Enemy objects on the Scene, in fact you have 4 instances of this script and each has own Evaporated variable)

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you move the void `OnCollisionEnter(Collision CollisionInfo)` to your `Enemy` scipt? I think `Enemy` should now if it collided with anything, not some external script.

You can also use tags instead of names when detecting Collisions.

Also, `gameObject.SetActive(false)` - if you set your gameObject to disabled, nothing more from its script will happen unless you set it to active again. It e.g. cancels all Coroutine. The gameObject is just "sleeping", I would say. It's not destroyed - you still can see it in your Hierarchy window - but it can't do anything. (By the way, in this case you're setting `EnemyEvaporate` gameObject as disabled, not `Enemy` gameObject.)

Also, you can use [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) instead of `Thread.Sleep(15)`. It is more common to use Coroutines than Threads in Unity.

Now, Evaporation. If you want to count how many Enemies evaporated (I suppose, looking at `Evaporated++;`) you should have some external object to count it. The simplest way I can propose fow now is creating a GameObject with `EvaporationCounter : MonoBehaviour` script attached to it. You can also use Singleton pattern to be sure there's only one object of this type.

```
public class EvaporationCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int evaporates;

    public int Evaporates {
        get { return evaporates; }
        private set
        {
            if (value >= 0) evaporates = value;
        }
    }

    public void AddEvaporation()
    {
        Evaporates++;
    }
}
```

Your Enemy class could look like:

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private IEnumerator coroutine;

    private EvaporationCounter evaporationCounter;

    private void Start()
    {
        evaporationCounter = FindObjectOfType<EvaporationCounter>();
    }

    private IEnumerator WaitAndSetInactive(float waitTime)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision CollisionInfo)
    {
        if (!CollisionInfo.gameObject.CompareTag("Map") && !CollisionInfo.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) return;
        if (evaporationCounter != null)
            evaporationCounter.AddEvaporation();
        StartCoroutine(WaitAndSetInactive(15f));
    }
}
```

Calling `evaporationCounter.AddEvaporation()` from the Enemy script is not the best solution, since it does not apply to the [Dependency Inversion principle](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design#toc-dependency-inversion-principle) but I would say it's good for the beginning with Unity.